# How to reuse port in socket server application?

Tags: c, sockets, server, port

I am trying to write a basic server socket program. I use the following code to bind the server socket.

```
/* Bind the server socket */
if (bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("Failed to bind the server socket");
    exit(1);
}
```

When I run the program for the first time, it works fine but when I run it the second time, I get this error:

[image: error]

I think when I run the program second time, it gives this error because the port was already linked to program which I run the first time. Can someone tell me how to close the port currently in use? Or suggest me something else which can solve this error.

Comment: how about `close()` https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

Comment: wait for 5-10 mins and run the program again..

Comment: @KamiKaze I already have `close()` in my program but when I terminate program using ctrl^c, `close()` is not helpful.

Comment: restart your machine or wait for some time.

Comment: Waiting for some time does help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill the process that binds the port:

```
 fuser -TERM 80/tcp #kills processes on tcp port 80 using signal SIGTERM
```

and start again.

TCP sockets normally aren't reusable for a while (a few minutes), unless they had the `SO_REUSEADDR` option set (with `setsockopt`) before they were bound.

(This option somewhat decreases robustness, but should be fairly safe to use in a testing environment.)

Comment: I tried to kill the process that binds the port but it doesn't work. I still have to wait for few minutes to reuse the port.